# How to eliminate the empty strings inside the object in android json parsing

Tags: android, json, parsing

Hi friends i like to parse the json from url and also like to elimate the null values field and only show the object which has value if anyone known syntax for that means please guide me thanks in advance.

> JSON Structure

```
{
    "daftar_rs": [
        {
            "Name": "exe1",
            "URL": "http://samir-mangroliya.blogspot.in/p/android-json-parsing-tutorial.html"
        },
        {
            "Name": "exe2",
            "URL": "https://code.google.com/p/json-io/"
        },
        {
            "Name": "exe3",
            "URL": ""
        },
        {
            "Name": "exe4",
            "URL": "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10964203/android-removing-jsonobject"
        },
        {
            "Name": "exe5",
            "URL": ""
        },
        {
            "Name": "exe6",
            "URL": ""
        }
    ],
    "success": 1
}
```

> MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ListView lv;
    List<String> titleCollection = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> urlCollection = new ArrayList<String>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

        // we will using AsyncTask during parsing 
        new AsyncTaskParseJson().execute();
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                  String linkUrl = urlCollection.get(arg2);
                   Intent webViewIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, WebViewActivity.class);
                   webViewIntent.putExtra("url", linkUrl);
                   startActivity(webViewIntent);

            }
    });
    }

    public void loadContents() 
    {
     ArrayAdapter<String> adapter =new ArrayAdapter<String>(getBaseContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,titleCollection);
     lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    // you can make this class as another java file so it will be separated from your main activity.
    public class AsyncTaskParseJson extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        final String TAG = "AsyncTaskParseJson.java";

        // set your json string url here

        String yourJsonStringUrl = "http://192.168.1.167/vinandrophp/vinex.php";

        // contacts JSONArray
        JSONArray dataJsonArr = null;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {}

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {

            try {

                // instantiate our json parser
                JsonParser jParser = new JsonParser();

                // get json string from url
                JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(yourJsonStringUrl);


                // loop through all users
                for (int i = 0; i < dataJsonArr.length(); i++) {

                    JSONObject c = dataJsonArr.getJSONObject(i);

                    // Storing each json item in variable

                    titleCollection.add(c.getString("Name"));
                    urlCollection.add(c.getString("URL"));


                    // show the values in our logcat
                    Log.e(TAG, "Name: " + titleCollection 
                            + ", URL: " + urlCollection);

                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String strFromDoInBg) {
             loadContents();

        }
    }
}
```

JsonParser.java

```
    public class JsonParser {

        final String TAG = "JsonParser.java";

        static InputStream is = null;
        static JSONObject jObj = null;
        static String json = "";

        public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) {

            // make HTTP request
            try {

                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();           

            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {

                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "n");
                }
                is.close();
                json = sb.toString();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error converting result " + e.toString());
            }

            // try parse the string to a JSON object
            try {
                jObj = new JSONObject(json);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
            }

            // return JSON String
            return jObj;
        }
    }
```

Comment: take a look at `Gson`. It does everything for you. `Gson` link: https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

Answer (score 1):

Just check it inside your code.

```
String linkUrl = urlCollection.get(arg2);

if (linkUrl== null || linkUrl.equals("")){
    // null
}
else{ 
    // not null so put to extras and start intent
    Intent webViewIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, WebViewActivity.class);
    webViewIntent.putExtra("url", linkUrl);
    startActivity(webViewIntent);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try below code

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataJsonArr.length(); i++) 
{
    JSONObject c = dataJsonArr.getJSONObject(i);
    // Storing each json item in variable

    String Name = c.getString("Name"); 
    String Url = c.getString("URL")

    if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(Name) && !TextUtil.isEmpty(Url)) 
    {
        titleCollection.add(Name);
        urlCollection.add(Url)); 
    }

    // show the values in our logcat
    Log.e(TAG, "Name: " + titleCollection + ", URL: " + urlCollection);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try below code:-

```
if(c.getString("URL").equals("") || c.isNULL("URL"))
{
     // do nothing
}
else
{
     titleCollection.add(c.getString("Name"));
     urlCollection.add(c.getString("URL"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change for loop as

```
       for (int i = 0; i < dataJsonArr.length(); i++) {

                JSONObject c = dataJsonArr.getJSONObject(i);

                // Storing each json item in variable
                String name = c.getString("Name");
                String url = c.getString("URL");
                if(name != null && !(name.equals("")) 
                          && url != null && !(url.equals(""){
                     titleCollection.add(c.getString("Name"));
                     urlCollection.add(c.getString("URL"));                
                }



                // show the values in our logcat
                Log.e(TAG, "Name: " + titleCollection 
                        + ", URL: " + urlCollection);

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replace keys and values with regular expression if the key is empty in the JsonParser class.

```
json=json.replaceAll("\\n",""); //you should do not have any new lines after commas
json=json.replaceAll(",\\W*\"\\w+\":\\W?(\"\"|null)","");
```